# Openshift Origin multicast support?

Tags: openshift-origin

we are using openshift origin with multi tenant plugin. Will multicast work between the pod network ? ( We are using the default 10.1.0.0/16 as cluster network CIDR)
[This link talks about it, although I do not have the subscription](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/774053)

Comment: I saw some good news in [the mentioned Trello card](https://trello.com/c/zL38DKU8/38-8-multicast-support-functionality). It is Completed and Accepted. The related multicast bugs found are fixed. Also [the mentioned knowledge base item](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/774053) has Solution Verified status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link is about OpenShift 2.x anyway. (And the answer there is "no".)

OpenShift 3.x does not currently support multicast either, but there has been discussion of adding it (https://trello.com/c/zL38DKU8). It is not currently scheduled for any release.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Our specific requirement was for Hazelcast and we are good using the kubernetes API . http://blog.hazelcast.com/openshift/